# refocus and select inputbox content inside change event

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I have 3 input boxes (`id="qprice1"`, `id="qprice2"`, `id="prev_value"`). if the value in `#qprice2` is smaller than `#qprice1`, I need to refocus and select all (highlight) the content of `#price2`. but it keeps focusing on the next element.

this is my code so far

```
$('body').on('change', '#qprice2', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var val1 = parseInt($('#qprice1').val().replace(/\D/g, ''));
  var val2 = parseInt($(this).val().replace(/\D/g, ''));
  if (val2 < val1) {
    alert('no reduction allowed!');
    $(this).val($('#prev_value'));
    $(this).focus().select();
  }
});
```

using timeout also didn't work:

```
setTimeout(function() { $(this).focus().select(); }, 100);
```

I also tried focusing to another element first but it didn't work as well

```
$('#qprice1').focus();
$(this).focus().select();
```

but when I try to focus and select an input box other than itself, it works fine:

```
$('#another_input').val('2000').focus().select();
```

how do I achieve the expected behavior? or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to attach the event handler to the input, rather than the body.

```
// handle click and add class
$('#qprice2').on('change keyup', function(e) {
var $t = $(this);
  e.preventDefault();
  clearTimeout(myvar);
  var myvar = setTimeout(function() {
    var val1 = parseInt($('#qprice1').val().replace(/\D/g, ''));
    var val2 = parseInt($t.val().replace(/\D/g, ''));
    if (val2 < val1) {
        $t.focus().val($('#prev_value').val()).select();
    }
  }, 1500);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sgqv1ch2/

Comment: still not highlighting the content of `#qprice2`.. it only changes the value.

Comment: @dapidmini Weird, it's highlighting it for me in the fiddle. What browser are you using? Can you share the html and css for the elements too? That might give an indication as to the problem.

Comment: I'm using mozilla firefox version 60.0.2 on windows pro 64bit. I opened your jsfiddle on the same browser.

Comment: @dapidmini : I've updated my fiddle, and forked it into a fresh url, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sgqv1ch2/). Basically it looks for change and keyup, waits 1.5seconds and then tests/changes. I've updated my original post, too.